# How to handle dynamic tables and fill the data in test rigor

Tags: testrigor

How to handle dynamic tables and fill the data in test rigor.

We have tables displayed according to the item selected and number of rows vary based on the item, our goal is to fill some column data. how to achieve this using test rigor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional (if exist) for an unknown amount of rows.
As an example, consider the following table which has rows
101, 102, and 103:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMRw8.png)

Let's assume that the table's amount of rows can vary from 1 to 5 rows or more.
In this case from 101 to, say, 105.  Well, the following conditional should
handle the extra rows if they exist:

---

enter "It's a trap!" into table "actions" at row "101" and column "Additional Data" if exist

enter "It's a trap!" into table "actions" at row "102" and column "Additional Data" if exist

enter "It's safe." into table "actions" at row "103" and column "Additional Data" if exist

enter "Where am I?" into table "actions" at row "104" and column "Additional Data" if exist

enter "Hello There!" into table "actions" at row "105" and column "Additional Data" if exist